# Calling a JS event handler from a Shell script

Tags: javascript, jquery, bash, shell, jenkins

I'm trying to click on a button in a html page after Jenkins has completed the build. The element ID is given below:

```
<a class="xcs-webui-bot-list-item-integrate-button show">
        Integrate
    </a>
```

This button also has a event handler

```
handleIntegrateHasBeenClicked: function handleIntegrateHasBeenClicked()
```

This page has a URL too. `(ex: https://myServer/xcode/bots/latest )`

Is there a way I can call this method from a Shell Script? This script is to be called in the Post-build Actions via 'Build another Project' in Jenkins.

Comment: do you mean click a button in a page open in chrome at the time the shell script runs?

Comment: Yes. This script is expected to be called in Jenkins - Post-build Actions.

Comment: the simplest way i can think of is to open a special url on the same domain as your page from the shell script. the page on that url has a small script that writes a value to `localStorage`. on the main page, you add a `storage` event to window, and put `handleIntegrateHasBeenClicked()`in there. then, when a new tab opens to that special URL, the storage event will fire on your page and click the button. yeah, that's the _simplest_...